# How to finish this Diophantine equation that has no integer values

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:
In a promotion, tickets were sold for €1.8 for adults and €0.75 for kids
Kids could only go if they were with their parents(2).
The last night they got €90 for selling the tickets.
Suppose that there were more adults than kids and there were at least one kid, how many people came to the party?

My attempt:

1.8x + 0.75y = 90

180x + 75y = 9000

Gcf(180,75) = 3

180x + 75y = 9000 --> /3

60x + 25y = 3000

60x + 25y == 3000(mod 60)

0x + 25y == 0 (mod 60)

And I got stuck from here. Any answers would help me a lot

Comment: It seems to me that you need to consider how many kids each family has (plus any single adults).  I would first try to do it under the (probably false) assumption that there were only one child families + single adults.  If that fails, then allow two children families, and so on.

Comment: Note:  a quick search finds several solutions, so either the answer is not unique or you left off some assumptions.

Comment: Note that GCF$(180,75) = 15$ (not $3$).